# Trying to display image in php using <img src=""> while getting data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, infowindow

I have a code to display locations on google maps. I am trying to display an image for each location in the infowindow. The image column in mysql has value "images/imagename". I looked at a lot of responses on this forum for similar questions but its not working for me. With below code i get a broken image icon. If i use the url directly then i am able to display the image but that wont work with multiple markers. I have tried to echo it in different ways but its not working.

```
var infoWindowContent = [
    <?php if($result2->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            ['<div class="info-content">' +
            '<div class="row"><img src="<?=$row["img"]?>"></div>' +
            '<h3 style="background-color: #eb52c7; color: white"><?php echo $row['name']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row['address']; ?></h3>' +
            '<p style="background-color: #eb52c7; color: white"><?php echo $row['info']; ?></p>' + '</div>'],
    <?php }
    }
    ?>
];
```

[image: brokenImage]

Comment: What is value of $row["img"] variable? If it contains local or global path? Please post example

Comment: `<?= ... ?>` doesn't work between quotes. Concat your variable to the string instead

Comment: I don't know what's going on here but it looks quote confused. If this is supposed to be JSON output, use a proper [JSON serializer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). If it's supposed to be HTML, don't flip back and forth between PHP mode so much.

Comment: $row["img"] this value is local path, "images/pic1.jpg"